# C - How to return the key of a tree that is found using the size of the data in the tree?

Tags: c, vector, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I have a binary tree and each node has this footprint. The tree is balanced by the key.

```
struct node
{
   STRING key;
   VECTOR data;
   struct node left;
   struct node right;
}
```

I want to have a function that will return the key of a node that has the largest data vector.
size(data) returns the size of the data; I want to use such a function like STRING largest = get_largest_key(MYTREE);
Thank you.

Comment: welcome to SO , can you please show us your attempt , what you have tried till now .

Comment: Yes, right now this works but the code is really really bad.
http://pastebin.com/uLv6ppL5

Answer (score 0):

You can also obtain a traversal of your tree, and then perform a linear search. I can't think of a faster method, since your tree is ordered by the key, not by the size of data.

Comment: Do you mind providing some basic code to do this? I'm drawing a blank. Thanks

Comment: @user3576699 I just saw your pastebin link. The code in it seems to be solid. What problems are you running into?

Comment: GCC was giving me a warning about control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]. If I add return NULL at the end to fix the warning it breaks the whole thing. I thought this code was actually sub-human scum.